# Erroneous Duplicate Root Nodes displayed in System.Windows.Forms.TreeView

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

I'm hoping someone will be able to shed some light on this.

I'm encountering an issue in the `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` control that is manifesting when I build an instance of a `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` in MS Video Studio 2017.

Basically - The first time it is built, everything looks as expected.  However, when I rebuild it at a later time (e.g.. after an update), the root node display gets duplicated.  Multiple updates result in the `TreeView` displaying increasing multiple root notes.

The nodes are cleared each time before the TreeView gets built and rebuilt ( e.g., `MyTreeView.Nodes.Clear()` ).

I was able to verify that the root nodes do not physically get duplicated.  The number of nodes in the `TreeView` (Nodes collection)  remain the same (1) and when i click on the duplicated root nodes and fall into debug (via my `MyTreeView_AfterSelect` event/routine), I can tell from the tag ID/hex handle that it is in fact the same (single) root node.  It's just being displayed twice in the visual aspect of the TreeView.

This tells me that there is a bug in the Treeview control itself.  I have researched this issue online in previous StackOverflow articles (as well as in a few other forums) and I have tried a number of suggestions/approaches to try to get around the problem.  To date, none have been successful for me.

Any suggestions/insights would, of course, be greatly appreciated.  I am at a loss as to what to do next.

Regards,

Christopher H. Fleetwood

Comment: Most likely the problem is with your code, so I suggest you post the relevant part. I also suggest you remove your email address from the posting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hel O'Ween, the issue is probably with the way its coded.

The issue I think is  with the command "TreeView.Nodes.Clear()" , it will Delete the "RootNode" as well as all other nodes and leave a "Blank" Duplicate entry in the system. If you run it again it will produce another Blank "Rootnode" entry which will cause havoc with you application as you have found.

The way to deal with it is to make the Root-Node Permanent. (It can be Set to ReadOnly - Hidden) Then just clear down the Childnodes that are attached to it.

Here is the vbcode i use to clear a treeview of all child nodes.

```
        Dim lngCount As Integer
        For lngCount = TreeView.Nodes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If lngCount - 1 = 0 Then Exit Sub
            TreeView.SelectedNode = TreeView.Nodes.Item(lngCount - 1)
            TreeView.Nodes.RemoveAt(lngCount - 1)
        Next
```

I did see an article on it once about never deleting the rootnode or you'll get a blank entry left! If i find it i'll add a link. It might only be vb.net with this issue.

Comment: This does make sense and does provide an explanation for my issue.  However, I implemented the child node remove(s) in my code and left the root node alone.  When I rebuilt my treeview nodes with the child information, I still ended up with the root node being duplicated in the TreeView display, exactly as before.  The Treeview variable displays the right node counts in debug, but is displaying the duplicate root node(s).

Comment: Couple of things : (1) I set my treeview up with a "ROOT" node. (2) This nodes checkbox was set to "TRUE". You can then check before removal : If TreeView.SelectedNode.Checked = True Then Exit Sub

Comment: I'm still seeing the dups issue.   I verified that only the "root" node remained after removing all other nodes (I even had the root node's checkbox set to "TRUE").  The root node alone displayed in the treeview after programmatically removing all nodes, but after executing the routine to populate the TreeView (which did not add a root node; that was done by another routine and only executed on the first population of the TreeView), the root node still duplicated (based on the dup tag ID/hex handles).  I can't set it to read-only/hidden as I need it to display in the TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass TreeNode objects ByRef.

Comment: Could add some more explanation? It's not clear how you infer that they pass treenodes ByRef and if they do, how that would cause the issue.

Comment: The symptoms match the additional phantom node that that is created but not accessible through the treeview.nodes enumeration when the node is passed byref to another method. As soon as the node is passed byref an extra level 0 node is added.